# why templateUrl not working?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

why templateUrl not working in angular 2.when I used template it works .It not work ..here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/WI4gK2vbaj4OUX5ImJor?p=preview

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
//  template: '<div (click)="onclck()">hello</div>'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
});
export class AppComponent {

  onclck(){
    alert('--')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have a semi-colon between `@View` decorator and your `export class AppComponent` in `app/script.ts`. Just remove it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Autosave might be turn off, just try saving home.component.html,home.component.ts and app.module.ts file

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to explain it a little bit, like why that one happens and why to follow your instructions.